# w3widgets responsive calendar Load events dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, calendar

I tried loading the events dynamically but did not get the output.
I brought data using AJAX in the format of

```
var datalist = "2015-09-22":{}

$(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({

  events: datelist

});
```

Comment: sac i cant use 'new' operator because it is use to initialize the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this in this CodePen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQGwpX

```
    var $cal = $('.responsive-calendar');
    var myevnts = {
        "2015-09-23": {}
      };

    $cal.responsiveCalendar({
      events : myevnts, /* end events */
    }); /* end $cal */
```

taken ref. from [this stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28758228/1659563)

Answer (score 0):

to add a single date to events,

```
var str= '{"'+yourDate+'":{}}';

$(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
     events: JSON.parse(str)
});
```

to add multiple dates to events,

```
var str = "";
for(j=0;j<yourDates.length;j++){
    if(j==0){
        str += '"'+yourDates[j]+'":{}';
    }else{
        str += ',"'+yourDates[j]+'":{}'; 
    } 
}; 
var dates= "{"+str+"}"; 
// Now,we got the format. {"2015-xx-xx":{},"2015-xx-xx":{},"2015-xx-xx":{}}
$(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
     events: JSON.parse(dates)
});
```

I hope it will help you. It works well in my calendar. Sorry if I wrong something. I'm just a newbie.